# How to decode json array to find the last value of a variable using Perl?

Tags: arrays, json, perl, decode

I have a Json array of objects that I am trying to decode in perl. The json array looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "name": "a123",
    "enroll": "12a123",
    "cs": {
      "year1": {
        "status": {
          "oldvalue": "pending",
          "new value": "complete"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "b123",
    "enroll": "12b123",
    "ecm": {
      "year1": {
        "flag": {
          "oldvalue": "null",
          "new value": "ok"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "c123",
    "enroll": "12c123",
    "cs": {
      "year1": {
        "status": {
          "oldvalue": "complete",
          "new value": "run new"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to find the value of the {"status"}->{"new value"} from the last occurrence in the Json file.The output here should be "run new". FYI : not all fields are present in every object. Any help on how to parse this array will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a module for this - CPAN has a [module called JSON:Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~bkb/JSON-Parse-0.49/lib/JSON/Parse.pod) which looks to do what you want:

```
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';
my $json = loadJsonString();   # Load the JSON string from somewhere
my $courses = parse_json($json);
my $lastCourse = $courses->[-1];
my $newValue = $lastCourse->{cs}{year1}{status}{"new value"};
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I am not sure if the status value is always in the last object. It could be in any object and I want to grab the last value of it. Also the year1 could be year2 with status . So how do we handle such a case ?

Comment: @JonSilva: What do you mean by *"last value"*?

Comment: @Borodin : The last value here refers to status value from the last objects in the array (order wise).

Comment: @JonSilva: That's what I assumed. So what do you mean by *"I am not sure if the status value is always in the last object"*? Also, there are two keys `cs` and one key `ecm`, and it seems unlikely that `year1` will always be the same. Do you know Perl at all? Your question has accumulated negative votes because you don't appear to have written any code that you want help to correct.

Comment: @Borodin : Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am new to perl and trying to read a json array objects. I am just using the json api. There is a different mechanism for generating the json file owned by others.

Comment: @JonSilva, are you looking for "the last object *that has a 'status' value*"?

Comment: `$lastCourse = (grep {exists $_->{cs}{year1}{status}} @$data)[-1];` or `($lastCourse) = reverse grep {exists $_->{cs}{year1}{status}} @$data);`